# Get documents based on conditional query of fields in mongoose js

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, conditional-statements

I am having model like this

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  locationtype: String,        // one of "all","locationstoshow","locationsnottoshow"
  locations: [{
    location_country: String,
    location_state: String,
    location_city: String
  }]
});

export default mongoose.model("AdPost", schema);
```

Now I have the values country, state and city of a current user.
I want to get those documents of adposts which satisfies these conditions -

if locationtype is "all", then all documents should be returned,

if locationtype is "locationstoshow", then every document should be checked whether current user's country, state and city is allowed. if yes, they should be returned. otherwise not.

if locationtype is "locationsnottoshow", then every document should be checked whether user's location is not included in locations and return it. otherwise not.

Please note that if city is not mentioned(i.e., location_city: "") and state&country are mentioned in locations, then user's country&state are checked And if country is only mentioned, and city&state and are "". then, user's country is matched.

I am thinking something like this but it is not giving the correct result.

```
let query = [{
        "$cond": {
            "if": {
                "$eq": [ "locationtype", "all" ]
            },
            "then": {
                "$match": [{
                    "$cond": {
                        "if": {
                            "$neq": [ "locations.location_city", "" ]
                        },
                        "then": {
                            "$neq": [ "locations.location_city", "" ]
                        },
                        "else": {
                            "if": {
                                "$neq": [ "locations.location_state", "" ]
                            },
                            "then": {
                                "$eq": [ "locations.location_state", "" ]
                            },
                            "else": {
                                "$eq": [ "locations.location_country", "" ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]
            },
            "else": {
                "if": {
                    "$eq": [ "locationtype", "locationstoshow" ]
                },
                "then": {
                    "$match": [{
                        "$cond": {
                            "if": {
                                "$neq": [ "locations.location_city", "" ]
                            },
                            "then": {
                                "$eq": [ "locations.location_city", `${city}` ]
                            },
                            "else": {
                                "if": {
                                    "$neq": [ "locations.location_state", "" ]
                                },
                                "then": {
                                    "$eq": [ "locations.location_state", `${state}` ]
                                },
                                "else": {
                                    "$eq": [ "locations.location_country", `${country}` ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                },
                "else": {
                    "if": {
                        "$eq": [ "locationtype", "locationsnottoshow" ]
                    },
                    "then": {
                        "$match": [{
                            "$cond": {
                                "if": {
                                    "$neq": [ "locations.location_city", "" ]
                                },
                                "then": {
                                    "$neq": [ "locations.location_city", `${city}` ]
                                },
                                "else": {
                                    "if": {
                                        "$neq": [ "locations.location_state", "" ]
                                    },
                                    "then": {
                                        "$neq": [ "locations.location_state", `${state}` ]
                                    },
                                    "else": {
                                        "$neq": [ "locations.location_country", `${country}` ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    },  
                }
            }
        }
    }];

const options = {
    limit: 10,
    page: pageNo
}

AdPost.aggregatePaginate(query, options).then(docs => {
    res.json({ docs });
}).catch(err => {
    res.status(400).json({ errors: err });
})
```

Comment: Post your code which you did so far

Comment: It appears that you're trying to code you application's logic into a MongoDB query. You have 3 different rules on what to return, why not create this logic in the application and have 3 different queries? It will be easier to read and debug.

Comment: Actually, I am making a social feed app where this logic is for the Admin post. Admin while writing a post, he selects the locationtype and locations. When a user opens his timeline, the posts should be shown along with these admin posts using the above logic. So, only one query should be executed for fetching these admin posts to the user. That's the problem.